# What is the easiest way to parallelize a vectorized function in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, vectorization

I have a very large list `X` and a vectorized function `f`. I want to calculate `f(X)`, but this will take a long time if I do it with a single core. I have (access to) a 48-core server. What is the easiest way to parallelize the calculation of `f(X)`? The following is *not* the right answer:

```
library(foreach)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()

foreach(x=X, .combine=c) %dopar% f(x)
```

The above code will indeed parallelize the calculation of `f(X)`, but it will do so by applying `f` separately to every element of `X`. This ignores the vectorized nature of `f` and will probably make things *slower* as a result, not faster. Rather than applying `f` elementwise to `X`, I want to split `X` into reasonably-sized chunks and apply `f` to those.

So, should I just manually split `X` into 48 equal-sized sublists and *then* apply `f` to each in parallel, then manually put together the result? Or is there a package designed for this?

In case anyone is wondering, my specific use case is [here](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/semi-global-alignment-tool).

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that `f` transparently makes use of MPI for parallelization if it finds it. So now I just have to figure out how to set up MPI.

Comment: This is a really good question. But I'm missing one thing (at least... probably more than one). If X is a list can you really run the vectorized function f() on it? Seems like X would need to be a vector or matrix to benefit from the vectorization inside of f().

Comment: You'll want to use multicore rather than MPI on a single machine; MPI will spin up 48 instances of R on the same machine, and duplicate data 48 times. Ouch. Split X into 48 approximately evenly sized chunks, do f(chunk), and figure out how to stitch them together again; you could do this with doMC where the foreach is over the chunks rather than the raw elements.

Comment: Actually, the function takes an instance of "DNAStringSet" class, which is a container for a list of DNA sequences, and `X` is an instance of this class. But the point is that it is vectorized, i.e. `f(X)` is exactly what I want to do, only faster. Expanding on my previous comment, the implementation of `f` automatically uses MPI if it is set up correctly. So I guess I now have to decide whether it is easier to set up MPI on this one server, or to do the chunking myself.

Comment: Sounds like pairwiseAlignment; for pattern `p`, subject `s` and `cores=2` e.g., `tasks <- split(seq_along(p), cut(seq_along(p), cores))` and `mclapply(tasks, function(i, p, ...) pairwiseAlignment(p[i], ...), p, s, scoreOnly=TRUE)` versus `pairwiseAlignment(p, s, scoreOnly=TRUE)`. Execution time is 2x (for my two cores) and results are identical. More challenging to merge the objects if not scoresOnly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The itertools package was designed to address this kind of problem.  In this case, I would use `isplitVector`:

```
n <- getDoParWorkers()
foreach(x=isplitVector(X, chunks=n), .combine='c') %dopar% f(x)
```

For this example, `pvec` is undoubtably faster and simpler, but this can be used on Windows with the doParallel package, for example.

Comment: Good answer. I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer because it is the most portable (pvec is non-windows). Also, one could implement a foreach-based pvec as follows: `fpvec <- function(v, FUN) foreach(x=isplitVector(v, chunks=getDoParWorkers()), .combine='c') %dopar% f(x)`.

Answer (score 6):

Although this is an older question this might be interesting for everyone who stumbled upon this via google (like me): Have a look at the `pvec` function in the `multicore` package. I think it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Is there a similar function for those of us running R on windows?

Comment: Zach: I think you should have a look at revolution R, which is a version of R for Windows that focuses on parallel processing. Think the best way to do it would be to use a %dopar% approach with the doSMP package as backend. Ryan Thompsons's answer should be able to use that nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my implementation. It's a function `chunkmap` that takes a
vectorized function, a list of arguments that should be vectorized,
and a list of arguments that should not be vectorized (i.e.
constants), and returns the same result as calling the function on the
arguments directly, except that the result is calculated in parallel.
For a function `f`, vector arguments `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, and scalar
arguments `s1`, `s2`, the following should return identical results:

```
f(a=v1, b=v2, c=v3, d=s1, e=s2)
f(c=v3, b=v2, e=s2, a=v1, d=s1)
chunkapply(FUN=f, VECTOR.ARGS=list(a=v1, b=v2, c=v3), SCALAR.ARGS=list(d=s1, e=s2))
chunkapply(FUN=f, SCALAR.ARGS=list(e=s2, d=s1), VECTOR.ARGS=list(a=v1, c=v3, b=v2))
```

Since it is impossible for the `chunkapply` function to know which
arguments of `f` are vectorized and which are not, it is up to you to
specify when you call it, or else you will get the wrong results. You
should generally name your arguments to ensure that they get bound
correctly.

```
library(foreach)
library(iterators)
# Use your favorite doPar backend here
library(doMC)
registerDoMC()

get.chunk.size <- function(vec.length,
                           min.chunk.size=NULL, max.chunk.size=NULL,
                           max.chunks=NULL) {
  if (is.null(max.chunks)) {
    max.chunks <- getDoParWorkers()
  }
  size <- vec.length / max.chunks
  if (!is.null(max.chunk.size)) {
    size <- min(size, max.chunk.size)
  }
  if (!is.null(min.chunk.size)) {
    size <- max(size, min.chunk.size)
  }
  num.chunks <- ceiling(vec.length / size)
  actual.size <- ceiling(vec.length / num.chunks)
  return(actual.size)
}

ichunk.vectors <- function(vectors=NULL,
                           min.chunk.size=NULL,
                           max.chunk.size=NULL,
                           max.chunks=NULL) {
  ## Calculate number of chunks
  recycle.length <- max(sapply(vectors, length))
  actual.chunk.size <- get.chunk.size(recycle.length, min.chunk.size, max.chunk.size, max.chunks)
  num.chunks <- ceiling(recycle.length / actual.chunk.size)

  ## Make the chunk iterator
  i <- 1
  it <- idiv(recycle.length, chunks=num.chunks)
  nextEl <- function() {
    n <- nextElem(it)
    ix <- seq(i, length = n)
    i <<- i + n
    vchunks <- foreach(v=vectors) %do% v[1+ (ix-1) %% length(v)]
    names(vchunks) <- names(vectors)
    vchunks
  }
  obj <- list(nextElem = nextEl)
  class(obj) <- c("ichunk", "abstractiter", "iter")
  obj
}

chunkapply <- function(FUN, VECTOR.ARGS, SCALAR.ARGS=list(), MERGE=TRUE, ...) {
  ## Check that the arguments make sense
  stopifnot(is.list(VECTOR.ARGS))
  stopifnot(length(VECTOR.ARGS) >= 1)
  stopifnot(is.list(SCALAR.ARGS))
  ## Choose appropriate combine function
  if (MERGE) {
    combine.fun <- append
  } else {
    combine.fun <- foreach:::defcombine
  }
  ## Chunk and apply, and maybe merge
  foreach(vchunk=ichunk.vectors(vectors=VECTOR.ARGS, ...),
          .combine=combine.fun,
          .options.multicore = mcoptions) %dopar%
  {
    do.call(FUN, args=append(vchunk, SCALAR.ARGS))
  }
}

## Only do chunkapply if it will run in parallel
maybe.chunkapply <- function(FUN, VECTOR.ARGS, SCALAR.ARGS=list(), ...) {
  if (getDoParWorkers() > 1) {
    chunkapply(FUN, VECTOR.ARGS, SCALAR.ARGS, ...)
  } else {
    do.call(FUN, append(VECTOR.ARGS, SCALAR.ARGS))
  }
}
```

Here are some examples showing that `chunkapply(f,list(x))` produces identical results to `f(x)`. I have set the max.chunk.size extremely small to ensure that the chunking algorithm is actually used.

```
> # Generate all even integers from 2 to 100 inclusive
> identical(chunkapply(function(x,y) x*y, list(1:50), list(2), max.chunk.size=10), 1:50 * 2)
[1] TRUE

> ## Sample from a standard normal distribution, then discard values greater than 1
> a <- rnorm(n=100)
> cutoff <- 1
> identical(chunkapply(function(x,limit) x[x<=limit], list(x=a), list(limit=cutoff), max.chunk.size=10), a[a<cutoff])
[1] TRUE
```

If anyone has a better name than "chunkapply", please suggest it.

### Edit:

As another answer points out, there is a function called `pvec` in the multicore pacakge that has very similar functionality to what I have written. For simple cases, you should us that, and you should vote up Jonas Rauch's answer for it. However, my function is a bit more general, so if any of the following apply to you, you might want to consider using my function instead:

- You need to use a parallel backend other than multicore (e.g. MPI). My function uses foreach, so you can use any parallelization framework that provides a backend for foreach.
- You need to pass multiple vectorized arguments. `pvec` only vectorizes over a single argument, so you couldn't easily implement parallel vectorized addition with `pvec`, for example. My function allows you to specify arbitrary arguments.

Comment: That's a very useful function you've written.  You should make an R package out of it!

Answer (score 0):

Map-Reduce might be what you're looking for; it's been [ported to R](http://opendatagroup.com/2009/09/10/mapreduce-reduced-ported-to-r/)

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has the same issue as my example in the question. It just takes a scalar function and vectorizes it in parallel. It doesn't parallelize an already vectorized function.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? R will take advantage of all the available memory and `multicore` will parallelize over all available cores.

```
library(multicore)
result = mclapply(X, function,mc.preschedule=FALSE, mc.set.seed=FALSE)
```

Comment: As with the foreach example, this will not take advantage of `f`'s vectorization.