# multicore programmation : master/slave system using package `parallel`

Tags: r, parallel-processing

**This question does not have an answer in** *What is the easiest way to parallelize a vectorized function in R?* as I am not asking for an easy way, but for an extra control on what the processes do and when then die, through a master/slave system.

Here is my problem: I used successfully `mcparallel` and `mccollect` to parallelize some tasks, along the following lines (`X` is a list) :

```
p1 <- mcparallel( lapply( X[1:25],  function(x) my.function(x, theta) ) )
p2 <- mcparallel( lapply( X[26:50], function(x) my.function(x, theta) ) )
p3 <- mcparallel( lapply( X[51:75], function(x) my.function(x, theta) ) )
x4 <- lapply(X[76:100], function(x) my.function(x, theta) )

c( mccollect(p1), mccollect(p2), mccollect(p3), x4 )
```

The elements of `X` are big, the parameter `theta` is small, and the aim is to perform optimization on `theta`. Note that `mclapply(X, ...)` performs *very* badly on my problem (almost no time gained). I also tried `%dopar%` from the `foreach` package: no time gained at all!

To reduce the overhead and avoid new forks at each computation, I’d like to use a master/slave logic as exemplified in [this Rmpi tutorial](http://math.acadiau.ca/ACMMaC/Rmpi/). I could feed the slaves new values of `theta`, this would avoid new forks at each new computation, with (I guess) copying the whole memory at each new fork, and so. As `theta` is small, and so are the results of `my.function`, the computation between the process would be fast and this would allow to gain a substantial amount of time in the subsequent computations.

However, I am told that MPI is a protocol which is more suited for using several computers. I use a multicore computer (16 cores), and I am told lighter protocols would be suited.

Can you give me an advice? In particular, is it possible to implement a master/slave system on a multicore computer, using the `parallel` package?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to parallelize a vectorized function in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5571774/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-parallelize-a-vectorized-function-in-r)

Comment: I take it that the elements of `X` are reasonably long vectors, but that you can't concatenate them in order to call `my.function` fewer times.  Is that true?  If so, there may not be much you can do.  But how much time do the different implementations actually take to run?

Comment: The elements of X are complex data structures, that have to be analyzed one at a time. The current implementation, on reasonably complex problems, runs in, say, one minute for the unparallelized version, and 20 secondes for the parallelized one, or so. Cutting in smaller chunks does not help much, the overhead being greater.

Comment: I guess I am just asking for a way, using `parallel`, to implement a master/slave system just as described in Rmpi. I’ll edit my question to make this clearer. This is not a duplicate of this previous question, I am not asking for an easy way (which would be for example `mclapply`).

Comment: @RyanThompson None of the answers given in this other question apply. I just want that the process created in the parallelization don’t die, as I think it will reduce the overhead in the next computations. My problem is really specific and different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of found a solution.

```
> library('parallel')
> makeCluster(2) -> cl
> # loading data to nodes:
> invisible(clusterApply( cl, 4:5, function(t) a <<- t ))
> # computations on these data with different arguments
> clusterApply( cl, 1:2, function(t) a+t )
[[1]]
[1] 5

[[2]]
[1] 7
> clusterApply( cl, 10:11, function(t) a+t )
[[1]]
[1] 14

[[2]]
[1] 16
> stopCluster(cl)
```

I think it will do what I want, but I still wait for other suggestions (hence I don’t accept my own answer).